# Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points... Custom Button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, authentication, instantiation

I'm new to programming on xCode. I've made a login screen in a snapchat format. Currently, I started with two view controllers one for login and then signup but I changed it so I start with an intial view controller that has two custom buttons I made. View the picture. I want it to be that so when you clean the login button it takes you to the login screen and when you click the sign up button it takes you to the sign up screen.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I want![enter image description here][1]

My app delegate has the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fWT4.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9mfN.png

I just don't understand as to why I keep getting the following error: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your segueing to the view in question, you would need to give it a storyboard identifier to connect the nib with the related class. Go into the storyboard and ensure you've set the class and storyboard id. If you're segueing to the class, ensure you give your segue an identifier. But if not, you can then do something like:

```
YourViewController *vc = (YourViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIndentifier:@"YourStoryboardIdentifier"];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{}];// Or however you want to present it. ie pushing onto the navigation stack
```

[image]

Comment: I've made sure that all 3 view controllers have classes, but my other 2 controllers don't have storyboard IDs. When I previously ran the project it worked fine. Y do I need the storyboard ID now? Ive given a story board ID to the view controller, but how do I connect the storyboard ID with the nib file? I don't understand what that exactly means. I've been reading about it. Basically this is what I want. A view controller that leads to two other controllers after clicking on either of the buttons: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/xcode/interface-builder/images/interface-builder.png

Comment: That screen shot has two push segues setup. So basically when you get each ibaction button callbacks, you would just do [self performSegueWithIndentifier:@"yourFirstSegueIdentifier"] and [self performSegueWithIndentifier:@"yourSecondSegueIdentifier"]. Create segues by control-dragging from one view controller to the next, choosing segue type, and then giving it a segue id. Does that make sense?

Comment: I already have two push segues setup from the SignUp button to the Signup view controller and from the login button to the login view controller. What do you mean by giving it a segue ID? Can this be the issue? http://i.stack.imgur.com/gYelm.jpg

Comment: Sadly, this is what I'm getting now: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<StartUpViewController 0x10a12bdf0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key loginTextField.'

Comment: That just means you have an outlet set up in Storyboard but the outlet does not exist in the related class. Delete that outlet and it will go away

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
WaitingRoomVC *ivc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"waiting"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
```